# Keep getting null reference on findViewById

Tags: android, imagebutton, navigation-drawer

I am trying to have a navigation drawer open and close with an ImageButton in Android Studio. My difficulty is that I'm not able to use certain methods because I am within a fragmented subclass. This is the error that I am getting.

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>           at dadump.test.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:27)

Here is my code that the error is being caused in. I also have a method called open() in my home activity that just has one line: `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);`.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

    ImageButton button = (ImageButton)getView().findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(android.view.View view) {
            ((MainActivity)getActivity()).open();
        }
    });
    return View;
    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation =findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        setupBottomNavigationView();
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());


    }

    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx)findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    }

    private boolean loadFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {

        if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ic_home:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.ic_directMessage:
                fragment = new DirectMessageFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.ic_newPost:
                fragment = new NewPostFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.ic_notifications:
                fragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.ic_userProfile:
                fragment = new UserProfileFragment();
                break;
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }

    public void open() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreateView` `getView()` is not initialized yet. That's why this issue is created. Try to use `view` instead of `getView()`. If you want to get data from `getView()` then move this code to `onViewCreated()`  `@Override` method.

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);

ImageButton button = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.button_settings);
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: So this fixed my error on the HomeFragment class but now I am getting a similar error in the MainActivity.java class

  `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(int)' on a null object reference
        at dadump.questions.MainActivity.open(MainActivity.java:74)
        at dadump.questions.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:31)` 

Could it be because I haven't initialized mDrawerLayout?

Comment: Yes. Would you please provide the MainActivity code?

Comment: I've made an edit to the original post to include my main activity code. I included the whole thing just in case, but I think the only part that matters is the open() method down below.

Comment: `mDrawerLayout` not initialized yet. Initialize first before use.